# Particles not responding properly to gravity issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some odd reason when I apply gravity to the particle system, all of the particles fly left downward. They are supposed to fly up and then down when you add gravity but for some reason why I do it it fly s to the left.  does anybody know what my problem might be?

Comment: We are going to need more information than this to help you. Especially screenshots of your particle system settings would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinate system is probably broken.

Gravity is applied in downwards direction globally, so if your global down points towards the left side, that would explain this effect.

The same applies if your up movement is not actually straight up. Depending on how you implement your upwards movement, applying gravity will cancel out all upwards components of the movement and pull the particles down, but if they have a leftwards component in their movement, that will continue to apply and result in the particles drifting away.